# Ping error ping: -l flag: Operation not permitted

Tags: command-line, terminal, ping

**ping -n 5 -l 1500 www.google.com**

was reviewing a tutorial, ran this command through the terminal 
was expecting 5 ICMP with ms timestamps.

got back the error➜  ~ ping -n 5 -l 1500 www.google.com
ping: -l flag: Operation not permitted

is this some sort of root user thing or dealing with permission? or this command just strictly for windows. I'm on a mac OS with ohmyzsh terminal

Answer (score 0):

Only the superuser can preload packets. Are you sure `-l` is what you wanted to use?

From the [man page](https://www.manpagez.com/man/8/ping/):

> **`-l`** *`preload`*
>
> If *`preload`* is specified, **`ping`** sends that many packets as fast as possible before falling into its normal mode of behavior.  Only the super-user may use this option.

Comment: I'm following a tutorial and it told me to enter ping -n 1 -l 342 www.google.com into the command line. I got a similar error. What is a superuser? I'm the admin on my machine. What do I need to do to make it work?